# Can't get polylongdiv to work

Tags: polynom

I've tried to use the package `polynom`.

I've used the following command:

```
\polylongdiv[style=C]{z^4-8z^3+39z^2-122z+170}{z^2+8}
```

But my polynom division ends up like this:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
\polylongdiv[style=C]{z^4-8z^3+39z^2-122z+170}{z^2+0z+8}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Help us help you by providing a [Minimum Working (compiling) Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe), with, `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin` and `\end{document}` and relevant packages, so that we can replicate the issue and provide a solution!

Comment: Never mind - worked when I used x as a variable instead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the manual of the `polynom` package, e.g. with the command `texdoc polynom` under Linux. You have to use `\polyset{vars=...}` (for a global change) or the option `vars=...` (for a one time change) to indicate what the variables are. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
% \polyset{vars=z} % alternative to option vars=z below
\polylongdiv[style=C,vars=z]{z^4-8z^3+39z^2-122z+170}{z^2+8}
\end{document}
```

gives the output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use it as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\mathcode`l=\lambda
\polylongdiv[vars=l,style=D]{-l^3+3l^2+l-3}{l-1}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

it gives:[image]

Comment: This seems to answer the question you posted as an answer earlier and not the question which was actually asked here. If you think that this is generally useful then you can ask a new question about this and then add this directly as an answer there. Here it will probably be deleted.